# Kivy packaging for android

Tags: android, kivy

I want to package kivy application via buildozer. I use instructions from  [here](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android-vm.html). Oracle Virtual box (version 5. 2. 4) is installed, but I cann't find file *Buildozer VM.ovf* (name from instructions). Where can I find this file or which parameters must I use to setting virtual machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cann't find file Buildozer VM.ovf (name from instructions)

Can be found in the bottom of [this page](https://kivy.org/#download). Link text is `kivy-buildozer-vm-2.0.zip`.

Comment: @ Spasibo Mikhail. I download file now and I will inform you about result.

Comment: I created "buildozer. spec" file, connect android device (Android 4.4.4). After sequention "buildozer android debug deploy run" I obtained message "I Check configuration tokens Unknown command/target android_old". Do I use really old version android or must I solve other problem?

Comment: @jasan I didn't face with this error before, but it seems to be a some bug in buildozer. Try to update buildozer running command `pip install -U https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/archive/master.zip` in your linux console and then try `buildozer android debug deploy run` again. If it won't help, only thing I can advice you is to write question to [Kivy users support group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kivy-users) as I found adviced in this [issue](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/124).

Comment: @ Origin of problem was in using virtual box. But I have next problem. You can see here; Kivy: Buildozer.spec file is not completed